# Database variables not getting updated immediately

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

In my Laravel app (I'm using Laravel 5.1, but this issue exists in Laravel 4 as well), I have a page for "user settings."  When a user updates their status from an "undergrad" to a "graduate" student and click "submit", the variable storing this status gets changed in the database.

My app then takes the user to a confirmation page saying their user settings were updated successfully.

However, on that page, I have a condition in the view which determined what menus are next displayed.  I have one set of menus for users who are undergrads, and another set of menus for users who are graduate students:

```
@if(Auth::user()->status == 'graduate')
    @include('graduate_menus')
@else
    @include('undergrad_menus')
@endif
```

For some reason, Auth::user still returns the previous value it had stored for the "status" variable.  If I click "refresh" on the page, then Auth::user returns the correct value.

I have temporarily fixed the problem by using Javascript to automatically refresh the page once.  However, it's an ugly hack and I would like to understand what I am doing wrong that Auth::user is not returning the value that was updated in the previous page's POST and if there is a way to fix it.  I think I might have to refresh the Session somehow, but I do not know how.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would be better if you save a variable status in the session. Update it whenever the user changes their status. In your page, check the user 's status against the status variable stored in the session and display the correct menu. Even better, now all pages have access to the same variable and you don't have to call Auth::user every time.

Comment: @mdamia I appreciate your suggestion, but I'm not totally clear on what you're saying.  Can you leave an answer and provide some code?  It sounds to me like you're saying to use the Session to store another variable, but my question is trying to get around the fact that the Session doesn't seem to update fast enough.  I look forward to seeing an example of what you're describing though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to set the updated user manually after you make changes to the user object, try this:

```
// Save done, you have $user
// with updated properties, so...

Auth::setUser($user);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  It appears to be working.  Any idea why Laravel doesn't just include running Auth::setUser($user) when $user->save() gets run?

Comment: Not sure but there must be some valid reasons :-)